# Data cursor in MATLAB stays blank

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm having a strange issue with MATLAB in that when I plot a surface, and I use the data cursor that no numbers show up in the little box that hovers over the cursor point.  I've attached a photo below to help understand:

[Data Cursor Not Showing Any Coordinates]([image: http://imgur.com/qeckKZx])  (

I've checked many other links on stackoverflow including:
[Erratic Data Cursors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449246/erratic-data-cursor-behavior-for-triangulated-3d-surfaces-in-matlab-r2011b), [Getting Data Cursor Coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22141770/how-to-get-coordinates-of-the-clicked-point-when-data-cursor-mode-is-on-in-matla),[Getting Coordinates of Clicked Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22141770/how-to-get-coordinates-of-the-clicked-point-when-data-cursor-mode-is-on-in-matla) however, they don't seem to answer my question (as far as I can understand.)

To be clear on exactly what I've been doing, I've run some simulations using [MIT Photonic Bands](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/MIT_Photonic_Bands), imported a surface into MATLAB, done some calculations on it and plotted it.  Below is the script of what I've done:

```
function [Kx,Ky,S] = BandSurface(k_1,k_2,B,b,z,p,varargin)

%Outputs:   Kx - The k_x "matrix" (from meshgrid) used to plot a surface
%           Ky - The k_y "matrix" used to plot a surface            
%           S - The band surface
%Inputs:    k_1 - the x-component of the k-point at which the band is
%                 calculated.
%           k_2 - the y-component.
%           B - the matrix holding all the bands, obtained from ReadBands.
%           b - indicated which band for which we want the surface.
%           z - whether (z=1) or not (z~=1) we want the band surface to be
%               (artificially) centered at (k_x,k_y)=(0,0).
%           p - Whether we want to plot (p=1) or not (p~=1)
%Optional Inputs:
%           m - If the G-X-M-Y-G quarter of the FBZ is spanned by vectors
%               k_x and k_y, m is the integer that indexes the point k_x(m)
%               at which we want to re-center the band surface.
%           n - The integer that indexes k_y(n) at which we want to
%               recenter the band surface.


%Check that the number of optional arguments does not exceed two.
nVarargin = length(varargin);
if nVarargin > 0 && nVarargin < 2
    error('Not enough optional input arguments!');
elseif nVarargin > 2
    error('Too many optional input arguments!');
end

%First thing we need to do is make a meshgrid of k_1 and k_2.  Get the
%unique values from k_1 and k_2.  This defines a quarter of the first BZ.
k_x = unique(k_1);
k_y = unique(k_2);

%Define the lengths of the unique vectors
nx = length(k_x);
ny = length(k_y);

%Now, we know how the band is set up.  We got the band structure for a
%quarter of the first BZ, between k_1={0, dkx, 2*dkx, ..., 0.5-dkx, 0.5} and
%analagous for k_2.
BS = zeros(nx,ny);

%Define the surface over the grid.
for i=1:nx
    for j=1:ny
        BS(i,j) = B((j-1)*ny+i,b);
    end
 end

%Now, make this over the entire first BZ.
gvx = linspace(-1*max(k_x),max(k_x),2*nx-1);
gvy = linspace(-1*max(k_y),max(k_y),2*ny-1);
[Kx,Ky] = meshgrid(gvx,gvy);

%Do the band surface
S = zeros(2*nx-1,2*ny-1);
for i=1:nx
    for j=1:ny
        S(nx-i+1,ny-j+1)=BS(i,j);
        S(nx-i+1,j+ny-1)=BS(i,j);
        S(i+nx-1,ny-j+1)=BS(i,j);
        S(i+nx-1,j+ny-1)=BS(i,j);
    end
end

%Define the k-point at which we want to center the distribution.
if nVarargin ~= 0
    m = varargin{1};
    n = varargin{2};

    %Try a different approach.  Let SS be the matrix which holds the
    %"four-folded" S matrix.

    %Let S1 be S.
    S1 = S;

    %Flip S1 to the left.
    S2 = fliplr(S1);

    %Concatenate everything except the last column of S2 to S1.
    SU = horzcat(S2(:,1:1:size(S2,2)-1),S1);

    %Flip S1 down.
    S4 = flipud(S1);

    %Flip S1 down and to the left
    S3 = fliplr(flipud(S1));

    %Concatenate everything except the last column of S3 to S4.
    SD = horzcat(S3(:,1:1:size(S3,2)-1),S4);

    %Now vertically concatenate SU and SD, except the first row of SD.
    SS = vertcat(SU,SD(2:1:size(SD,1),:));

    %Now, seeing Aug 25, 2014 notes, we find out the point in S1 (in the 3rd
    %quadrant of S1) where we want to center the band surface.  Then we find
    %out where this point lies in SS.  Then, take a subset of SS centered about
    %this point.
    S = SS(nx-1+m:1:3*nx-3+m,ny-1+n:1:3*ny-3+n);

    %Define a grid spacing.
    dkx = (k_x(length(k_x)) - k_x(1))/(nx-1);
    dky = (k_y(length(k_y)) - k_y(1))/(ny-1);

    %Now, redefine our grid vectors.
    gvx = linspace(k_x(m)-nx*dkx,k_x(m)+nx*dkx,2*nx-1);
    gvy = linspace(k_y(n)-ny*dky,k_y(n)+ny*dky,2*ny-1);
    [Kx,Ky] = meshgrid(gvx,gvy);
end

%Now, center the band surface at zero if we are asked to.
if z==1
    gvx = linspace(-nx*dkx,nx*dkx,2*nx-1);
    gvy = linspace(-ny*dky,ny*dky,2*ny-1);
    [Kx,Ky] = meshgrid(gvx,gvy);
end


%Plot it.
if p ==1
    figure();
    clf;
    surf(Kx,Ky,S);
    xlabel('k_x (2 \pi /a)');
    ylabel('k_y (2 \pi /a)');
end
end
```

(I know a lot of it may not make sense to everyone else, but I've included the whole function for completeness' sake.)  I don't think I've done anything out of the ordinary with respect to the plotting (see the bottom of my attached code) so I don't know why this is happening.

Also, it is worth mentioning that yesterday when I was debugging this function, I was using the debugger.  The data cursors were working fine.  Then, for some reason it spit out a warning about Print Templates.  After this warning, I figured restarting MATLAB would solve the problem but it didn't, and since other warnings occurred since that one, `lastwarn` doesn't return the warning and I can't seem to recover the warning about Print Templates that I mentioned.

Also, it should be noted that while the data cursor doesn't work on this machine, when I go to another machine, it seems to work just fine.

If someone could help me figure out why this is, I would greatly appreciate!

EDIT:  In the comments below patrik asked if this happened everytime.  To illustrate this, I made a simple parabloid over a range of X=[-3,3] and Y=[-4,4] of Z=3*X.^2+Y.^2.  If I do it with a small grid size as follows:

```
[X,Y]=meshgrid(-3:0.5:3,-4:0.5:4)
Z = 3*X.^2+Y.^2;
figure();
surf(X,Y,Z);
```

I get the following [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbMTF.jpg) and indeed the data cursor seems to work fine!

However, if I use a finer grid for the exact same parabloid as follows:

```
[X,Y]=meshgrid(-3:0.05:3,-4:0.05:4);
Z = 3*X.^2+Y.^2;
figure();
surf(X,Y,Z);
```

I get another figure (which I am not allowed to link to as my reputation is not high enough, but the link is `http://imgur.com/EWJv041`) in which the data cursor does not work!

So, to answer your questions, it doesn't happen all the time, but it seems to happen past a certain grid resolution.

Comment: You may consider the function `makedatatip` from the file exchange http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19877-makedatatip . This undocumented matlab page may help too http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/controlling-plot-data-tips

Comment: Is this happening every time?

Comment: Thanks for your replies.  @Macduff, I looked at the links you posted.  Even using the `makedatatip` function still yields the same problem.  I tried looking at the second link, and checked the data cursor's properties using `cursorMode.CurrentDataCursor.get` and they all looked almost the exact same as in the example posted (with the exception of some properties such as `HandleVisibility` and `HitTest` which I looked up and they seem to have nothing to do with this data cursor problem.).  @patrik, please see the edit in the post.

Comment: Can you tell what renderer your figure uses? (command is `get(gcf,'Renderer')` )

Answer (score 2):

I had the same exact issues as described. I also tested the behavior with the code provided. 
I'm running Matlab on a laptop with switchable graphic cards (Intel HD and AMD Radeon).

Solution:

Matlab was set for running with the AMD Processor.
After switching it to run with the integrated Intel HD it works again! The integrated Intel card is selected with the "Power saving" option.

Link to example: http://i62.tinypic.com/vfaxw3.jpg
Don't have reputation to post pictures yet.

Switching the graphics card can be done from the AMD Cataclyst Control Center. If the issue appears on Nvidia cards you can change it in the Nvidia control panel

Answer (score 0):

Here are my **suggestions** on how you can debug it, since I cannot reproduce your problem locally.

1. Try setting a breakpoint on top of `\<MATLAB Folder>\R201??\toolbox\matlab\graphics\@graphics\@datatip\datatip.m` and follow it for both the working example and the non-working one, and see if and when there's a difference.
2. Try saving the figure as a `.fig` and uploading it somewhere. If some settings (or default settings) of the figure are bad, it would be possible to compare it with a working figure created on a different computer and see where the difference is. [Here's a working figure](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=33264408484370976157) I made for your last example, including a datatip. If this figure works for you, I could suggest a workaround where you simply create an empty (and functional) figure file on a different computer (or use the one I uploaded) and just reuse the axes with your own data.
3. Try [backing up and then deleting](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/98438#answer_107788) your preferences folder. It is possible that you have some corrupt settings. (an unlikely but possible cause is a font\interpreter problem... It seems like your font is slightly different from mine, which works well, so resetting the preferences may help with that).

Please let me know if any of these worked for you.